# what are the ways to convert a simple array to 'nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, screenshot

I want to capture screenshots on my remote virtual machine without using display. I came across a library in nodejs **'capture screenshot'** (https://github.com/sindresorhus/capture-website) which is pretty straightforward.

Taking screenshot of a single link is fairly simple, however taking multiple screenshots becomes tricky. I don't want to put links manually as it will be time consuming. I am running a script to get all anchor tags in python and saving a csv file of links gathered. This is how it looks when I convert the saved csv file to a JavaScript array.

```
[ 'https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi',
  'https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl',
  'https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8',
  'https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&tab=w1',
  'https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn',
  'https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm',
  'https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo',
  'https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh',
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/',
  'https://www.google.com/url?q=https://lifeinaday.youtube/%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dhppcta%26utm_campaign%3D2020&source=hpp&id=19019062&ct=3&usg=AFQjCNEJMAD58Mjdnro8Mjm-RtJ3nfEIZA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98PWM4-HqAhVh1uAKHeYGCPwQ8IcBCAU'
 ]
```

I want to convert the above array to the array shown below.

```
[ 
  ['https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi', 'anyanme'],
  ['https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl','anyanme'],
  ['https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8','anyanme'],
  ['https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&tab=w1','anyanme'],
  ['https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn','anyanme'],
  ['https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm','anyanme'],
  ['https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo','anyanme'],
  ['https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh','anyanme'],
  ['https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/','anyanme'],
  ['https://www.google.com/url?q=https://lifeinaday.youtube/%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dhppcta%26utm_campaign%3D2020&source=hpp&id=19019062&ct=3&usg=AFQjCNEJMAD58Mjdnro8Mjm-RtJ3nfEIZA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98PWM4-HqAhVh1uAKHeYGCPwQ8IcBCAU','anyanme']
   ];
``
I am newbie to javscript and having a hard time to solve this. Any help will be appreciated.
```

Comment: @MrNobody33 sorry about that. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: What is the name do you want to give to the file? If you use the name of website then you may overwrite the previous link image.

Comment: Any name would be ok. I am just interested in the screenshots. There is no specific name i want to assign.

Answer (score 1):

You ca achieve it with a Map and regex

```js
const arr = ['https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi',
  'https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl',
  'https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8',
  'https://www.youtube.com/?gl=US&tab=w1',
  'https://news.google.com/nwshp?hl=en&tab=wn',
  'https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm',
  'https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo',
  'https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh',
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.com/',
  'https://www.google.com/url?q=https://lifeinaday.youtube/%3Futm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dhppcta%26utm_campaign%3D2020&source=hpp&id=19019062&ct=3&usg=AFQjCNEJMAD58Mjdnro8Mjm-RtJ3nfEIZA&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi98PWM4-HqAhVh1uAKHeYGCPwQ8IcBCAU',
  '',
];

function extractName(str) {
  const regex = /https:\/\/(.*?)\//g;

  const ret = regex.exec(str);
  
  return (ret && ret[1]) || null;
}

const items = arr.map(x => [
  x,
  extractName(x),
]);

console.log(items);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering
This gives me an individual array as this.
[
    "https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi",
    [
      "https://www.google.com/",
      "www.google.com"
    ]
  ]
however I only need this:
[
['my link' , 'filename'],
['my link2' , 'filename'2],
]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the library you're using wants an array of pairs, with a URL and a file name.

I would [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your original array to the array of pairs, but you'll have to figure out what you want to do for file names.

Assuming you have a function, named `toFileName` that will take a URL string and return a file name that you want for that URL, you could map the original array into the array of pairs like this:

```
const pairArr = originalArray.map((url) => {
    const fileName = toFileName(url);
    return [url, fileName];
});
```

If you just want to try to use the URL as the filename, you could just do this:

```
const pairArr = originalArray.map((url) => {
    return [url, url];
});
```

This will be an issue with most URLs, though, as they'll have characters that are invalid for filenames. If you need a file extension with this approach, you could use string concatenation (`url + '.png'`) for the second item in the returned pair.